# mysql - How to determine the length of a field which stores a mutable string?

Tags: python, mysql, json, sqlalchemy

I'm working on a iOS application and I use Flask(a Python framework) to build my backend.

I store my data in `mysql` database.

Now I need to store a bunch of IDs in one attribute.

Firstly I convert the array which stores the IDs to a `JSON` format object.

Then I ran into a problem. **How to store this object?**

As the length of the object can be rather large(I cannot make sure how many IDs I store), and `SQLAlchemy` **requires the attribute to have a exact length** when I create the table, so how to determine the length of the attribute?

Comment: I don't know SQLAlchemy, but you almost certainly want to declare this field as a TEXT type, which doesn't require a max length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quiet know the situation you meet , But it's not recommended to store multi records in one column , It's more normalised to build a relation map between `ID owner` and `ID` .

For example , you can create a new table called 'IDs' with schema like that :

```
id int auto increment ,
idbla varchar(<Your ID Length>)
owner int not null
```

When you are trying to get all `idbla` of some user `x` you can use

```
SELECT * idbla from IDs where owner = x
```

## Another choice :

You can use `nosql` (non relational database) to store your data , It's document like and fit your situation pretty well .

Comment: As I'm not quite experienced in database management, I just simply think about save all the IDs in one column because I'm afraid that it would take much time to search for every records if I do as you said in the **first choice**. But then I found it is not true. So the first choice seems to be a good solution for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### In case you use MySQL 5.7 or newer

you should look at the new [JSON type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

You can use this MySQL feature through sqlalchemy's [type.JSON](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON). This will greatly simplify column data management.

```
data_table = Table('data_table', metadata,
Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
Column('loosely_related_ids', JSON)
)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(
        data_table.insert(),
        loosely_related_ids = [1, 54, 56, 99, 104]
    )
```

Later on accessing the loosely_related_ids field will return a python array that you access normally.

### If you are using an older version of MySQL

you should use a TEXT field or a wrapper around a similar type.

SQLAlchemy provides the [PickleType field](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.PickleType) which is implemented on top of a BLOB field and will handle pickling and unpickling the array for you. Keep in mind that all the caveats of pickling python objects and sharing them across interpreters still apply here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use MySQL 5.6 actually but I will update it and give a try. :) But I think to create another table and save each of the ID as a single record might be a better choice! :) (Have a look at @KIDJourney's answer if interested)

Comment: I assumed that you actually needed to store a list of values on one column. If there are no extra requirements you should most definitely use the relational features of your _R_DBMS, and take a look at sqlalchemy basic relationship patterns http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many